# OpenCV install 'so' files not found cant insall via apt

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, apt, opencv, shared-libraries

Rasp 3 B+, Raspbian

I installed OpenCV using `pip3 install opencv-python`

Then tried to `import cv2` which threw the error..

```
ImportError: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After much searching I found [this blog post](https://blog.piwheels.org/how-to-work-out-the-missing-dependencies-for-a-python-package/) about missing dependencies & found that the following dependencies are missing,

```
libcblas.so.3
libatlas.so.3
libjasper.so.3
```

At this stage in the blog post it suggests using `apt-file` to find which packages need installing to get the missing `so`'s but when I try to install `apt-file` via `sudo apt install apt-file` I get the following error...

```
E: Unable to locate package apt-file
```

I get the same error if I try to install `libcblas-base` or `libjasper` which contain the missing `so`'s

(side note: I am assuming `libcblas` is an implimentation of the Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms library?)

So how do I get access to these missing packages & libraries? This is my first exposure to the world of Linux repositories by the way.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to run

```
sudo apt update
```

That needs to be done to find new versions. After that you can use apt to install the packages you need to get those libraries. For example libcblas.so.3 can be installed with

```
sudo apt install libcblas3
```

For reference rather than apt-file I just use things like

```
apt search libcblas
```

When I want something like libcblas.so.3 Then I pick the one that looks appropriate. Nothing wrong with apt-file it's just something else to install.

You also want to periodically run

```
sudo apt upgrade
```